# State is always initial value when attempting to update

Tags: reactjs

```js
export const ExecutionProvider = (props) => {
    const [output, setOutput] = useState([]);

    const handleOutput = (message) => {
        const newOutput = [...output];

        newOutput.push(message);

        setOutput(newOutput);
    }

    const runCode = () => {
        const parsedCode = parseCode(code);

        const codeBlob = new Blob([parsedCode], { type: 'application/javascript' });
        const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(codeBlob));

        worker.onmessage = handleOutput;
    }
```

The handleOutput function is used as a callback for a webworker running some code. Problem is the output array is always empty when I'm attempting to push the new message to it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using the callback method when updating state:

```js
  const handleOutput = (message) => {
      setOutput(previousOutput => [...previousOutput, message]);
  }
```